# Expected Command

Tags: netlogo

I think this is an error somewhere in my brackets, but I am not sure where this error is located.

```
to feed
  let prey one-of humans-here
  if prey != nobody [
    [ifelse random-float 1 <= zombie-victory-probability
    ifelse random-float 1 <= conversion-probability
      [ ask prey [ convert ] ]
      [ ask prey [ die ] ]
      [ die ]
  ]]
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hard to say for sure as I can't test without seeing your setup code, but maybe like this?

```
to feed
  let prey one-of humans-here

  if prey != nobody [
    ifelse random-float 1 <= zombie-victory-probability  
    [ ifelse random-float 1 <= conversion-probability ; option a1
      [ ask prey [ convert ] ] ; option b1
      [ ask prey [ die  ] ]    ; option b2
    ]   
    [ die ] ; option a2
  ]  
end
```

Comment: Alright, I see what the error was. The brackets in the ifelse had not been closed properly aveter either of the prey options.